# htaccess avoid GET vars(? and & chars)

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to avoid ? and & chars from the URL.

For example my php file is like this:

```
<?php 
$_GET["page"] = "page1";
?>
```

And, htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^page1$ index.php?page=page1
```

I want to give access to users only by typing www.example.com/page1 not by typing www.example.com/index.php?page=page1 .

Is there any way to make it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have another `301` rule on top to redirect users from your old URL to new pretty URL:

```
RewriteEngine On

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+index\.php\?page=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^page1/?$ index.php?page=page1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

example:

```
RewriteRule ^page/([0-9]+)? index.php?page=$1 [L]
```